# Package specific python source from private git repo in nixos

Tags: python, package, nix, nixos

My repo contains many other python programs. I want to package a specific python program from my private git repo in Nixos.But am not able to fetch a specific program from below trying::
one more doudt is.... where I have locate the **setup.py* file for this packaging.

anyone have any idea....heartfull thanks to helping mind....

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, specialArgs, options, modulesPath, czmq }:
  let 
       nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
       inherit (nixpkgs) czmq;
       repo = builtins.fetchGit {
        url = "ssh://myrepo-bot@mydomain.in:29238/prjct-build";
        ref = "v6.0.3";
      };
      prjct_service = pkgs.python310Packages.buildPythonPackage {
        pname = "prjct_service";
        version = "6.0.3-1";
        src = "${repo}/menu/prjct_service.py";
...........continues...
```